# function call seems not working properly in disassembled code

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple program and then compiled and assembled it.

**tfc.cpp**

```
int i = 0;

void f(int a)
{
  i += a;
};

int main()
{
  f(9);
  return 0;
};
```

I got the tfc.o by running

```
$ g++ -c -O1 tfc.cpp
```

Then I use **gobjdump** (**objdump**) to disassemble the binary file.

```
$ gobjdump -d tfc.o
```

Then I got

```
0000000000000000 <__Z1fi>:
   0: 55                    push   %rbp
   1: 48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4: 01 3d 00 00 00 00     add    %edi,0x0(%rip)        # a <__Z1fi+0xa>
   a: 5d                    pop    %rbp
   b: c3                    retq   
   c: 0f 1f 40 00           nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000000010 <_main>:
  10: 55                    push   %rbp
  11: 48 89 e5              mov    %rsp,%rbp
  14: bf 09 00 00 00        mov    $0x9,%edi
  19: e8 00 00 00 00        callq  1e <_main+0xe>
  1e: 31 c0                 xor    %eax,%eax
  20: 5d                    pop    %rbp
  21: c3                    retq
```

The weird thing happened, the `callq` instruction is followed by `1e <_main+0xe>`. Shouldn't it be the address of `<__Z1fi>`? If not, how does the `main` function call the `f` function?

**EDIT**
FYI:

```
$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Try `objdump -M intel -d tfc.o`.

Comment: I'm wondering if the disassembly isn't showing the callq -> jump to 0x00 <__Z1fi> ?

Comment: @ooga Still, I got `19: e8 00 00 00 00  call   1e <_main+0xe>`

Comment: See the answer provided by @GriffinG, it is helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls address 0, which is the address of the f function.

e8 is the call instruction in x86 according to this:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15213-s07/misc/asm64-handout.pdf

call uses the displacement relative to the next instruction, at memory location 1e. That becomes memory location 0. So it's callq 1e when in reality it's calling address 0.

Comment: Include in your answer the REASON the call address is all zeroes. The reason is that the linker is going to write the ACTUAL call address into that location after it links. That's called a relocation.

Comment: Got it. I should see the disassembled code after linking, which can be done by simply running `g++ tfc.cpp -o tfc`.

Comment: As Zan says, the actual call address hasn't been written in yet - that's why the object has 0s and the disassembler reports "callq  1e <_main+0xe>" - at link time the e8 00 00 00 00 will be have the address part overwritten with the 32 bit signed value for -0x1e, such that the callq pushes the return address of 0x1e hex then adds the two to call to `__Z1fi` at address 0.  After linking, disassembly will actually show the -0x1e bytes (E8 FF FF FF E2) and `callq __Z1fi`.

Comment: @TonyD It is actually `E8 E2 FF FF FF` on most machines because it is big-endian representation.